# Android: Nullpointer on location longitude?

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager

It's been three days that i'm getting this error (before it was working, so... don't know): nullpointer exception on location.getLongitude();
my simple code (the last code of onCreate()):

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    Double latitudine=location.getLatitude();
```

i get the nullpointer at the last line... and i repeat: it was working...
Thanks a lot.

LOGCAT:

```
07-24 16:11:23.125    1622-1622/it.avcommunication.tuodi E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'gpr', referenced from method gps.a
07-24 16:11:23.125    1622-1622/it.avcommunication.tuodi E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'gpr', referenced from method gps.a
07-24 16:11:23.125    1622-1622/it.avcommunication.tuodi E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'gpr', referenced from method gps.a
07-24 16:11:23.300    1622-1622/it.avcommunication.tuodi E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method glt.a
07-24 16:11:24.350    1622-1622/it.avcommunication.tuodi E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.avcommunication.tuodi/it.avcommunication.tuodi.Negozi}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at it.avcommunication.tuodi.Negozi.onCreate(Negozi.java:233)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
```

Comment: `getLastKnownLocation` can return null,

Comment: if you never used 'lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);', it dont have last location then return null to you.

Comment: not for three days in a row :-| not with 5 phones

Comment: have you switched off your device/gps? Still since it can return null you should care of it

Comment: because your location object is null simple.

Comment: turn on your device GPS because you are requesting LOCATION from GPS.

Comment: i don't want to be a bad person but... don't write things like this: it's obvious that i have gps and datacell turned on!!!

Comment: solved, it's an ADT bug. with the public key and an apk released, the location is ok

Answer (score 1):

`getLastKnownLocation` returns null if the device doesn't have a location lock previously.

Try turning on GPS and check.Also give a try opening Maps with your GPS turned on that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location loc = getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
     5000, 10, this);
```

Then in the onLocationChanged method try to do this :

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
}
```

Dont forget to implement the  LocationListener interface.

```
public class ActivityName extends Activity implements LocationListener {
```

Comment: your code is full of error (public, not Public) (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,not LocationManager.GPS) and locationListener is not recognised

Comment: where did you see LocationManager.GPS ?

Comment: lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS, 100, 1, locationListener);

Comment: Yes that's right try this :  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
   5000, 10, this);

Comment: I made changes in my answer

Comment: solved, it's an ADT bug. with the public key and an apk released, the location is ok